# Mask multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I've got multiple canvas elements and text inside a div. These canvases and text are added dynamically.

```
<div id="art_holder">
   <canvas class="stu_drawings1"></canvas>
   <div class="dra_category1">Text 1</div>

   <canvas class="stu_drawings2"></canvas>
   <div class="dra_category2">Text 2</div>

   <canvas class="stu_drawings3"></canvas>
   <div class="dra_category3">Text 3</div>
</div>
```

I want to mask all contents inside `#art_holder`. I wanted to try the masking by using a custom shaped inline svg and `clippath`. But it doesn't support none of the IE versions.

How can I mask all contents inside `#art_holder`?

Comment: Read this article: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: @Repo thanks. I already have gone through it. Doesn't work in IE.